Как подключить айфон как IP камеру
помогите подключить айфон в качестве IP камеры. Через web cam подключаюсь, но это когда в одной локальной сети и ПК и телефон, а находясь удаленно когда телефон подключен к интернету по 3G/LTE не получается соединится.

По моему skype имел функцию автоответ, можно ещё soft SIP-телефоны посмотреть и всякие jitsi, zoom итп. Или можно настроить VPN-mash сеть и внутри неё получить доступ к смартфону.

Ещё можно посмотреть в сторону ZeroTier

Здравствуйте спасибо за ответ, пробовал не получилось)

Для подключения через интернет нужен сервер. Попробуйте видеозвонок в один из бесплатных серверов видеоконференций или установите свой медиа сервер.

Здравствуйте понял спасибо, но это для меня очень сложная задача)
